# ¿ Como hacer un boton en html que se visualizable en Outlook 2007?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, outlook

Tengo que enviar un email en formato HTML donde aparecen algunos botones que envían a otro link. El problema es que  el cliente de correo Outlook 2007 no interpreta HTML moderno y no consigo hacer que me visualize bien el aspecto de un botón. He intentado hacerlo con el tag  dándole estilos pero no tiene aspecto de botón ya que el color de fondo del botón solo me ocupa el tamaño del texto. Si lo hago con el tag  me visualiza como si fuera un enlace.

Estos son algunos ejemplos que no funcionan para Outlook 2007:

```
<p align=center style='text-align:center'>
  <a href='' style='text-decoration: none;'>
    <button style='color: #ffffff; word-wrap: break-word; font-family: Arial Normal, Arial; border: none; -moz-box-shadow: none; -webkit-box-shadow: none; box-shadow: none; margin-right: 10px; background-color: #169BD5;'>CONFORME</button>
  </a>
</p>

<p align=center style='text-align:center'>
  <a href='' style='margin-bottom:10px; display: inline-block; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none; display: inline-block; border: 1px solid transparent; font-weight: normal; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; white-space: normal;padding: .45em 1em;font-size: 6.5pt; color: #fff; background-color: #169BD5;'>CONFORME</a>
</p>

<p align=center style='text-align:center'>
  <b>
    <span style='font-size:5.5pt;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding:2.5pt 2.5pt 2.5pt 2.5pt; background-color: #169BD5;  '>
      <a href='' style='color: white;  padding:2.5pt 2.5pt 2.5pt 2.5pt; text-decoration:  none;'>CONFORME</a>
    </span>
  </b>
</p>
```

Comment: Es muy raro eso del primer ejemplo, no tiene sentido meter un botón dentro de un enlace

Comment: Meto un boton dentro de un enlace para no usar javascript en el cliente de correo.

Comment: ¿Y no es mas sencillo maquetar un enlace como un botón?

Comment: entonces te sobra el botón, con el enlace es suficiente. No puedo probar como se ve en Outlook2007 porque no lo tengo pero debería funciona un enlace con `padding`. Si no puedes probar esto: https://buttons.cm/

Comment: He maquetado el enlace como un boton pero Outlook no me deja padding dentro del boton ( con el tag <span> )

Comment: Olvidate del span, maqueta sobre el enlace unicamente.

Comment: @blonfu ese enlace no me sirve ya que la solucion que dan es para html moderno y ademas crea el boton con un link a una imagen

Comment: @Popularfan No, Esa herramienta te crea un codigo que sirve para diferentes clientes de correo, en teoria funciona en Outlook2007. Además viene un ejemplo de botón pero puedes editarlo como quieras y te crea el código correspondiente.

Comment: @blonfu ok , lo he probado y funciona ! Esta  usa tags de Microsoft. Me gustaría encontrar otra solución que usara solo tags HTML aunque los botones salieran sin bordes redondeados.